# Pass user inputs from one script to another during runtime

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement where **ScriptA.sh** has commands to ask for User's inputs and perform a set of actions. I want to automate this by creating another script which will read the questions asked from output of ScriptA.sh and provide the necessary values in runtime.

ScriptA.sh as follows :-

```
echo "Enter the CR Number"
read varnamecr
echo "CR Number is" $varnamecr
echo "Loading the config set. Choose Option From Below set
1.JAN
2.FEB
3.MAR"
read optionchoosen
echo "Option Choosen is :" $optionchoosen
echo "Will run the script/load configuration is this Ok ?[y/N]"
read userinput
echo "Proceed further, User has pressed ->"$userinput"<--Key"
```

How to write the second script to achieve this. Tried `spawn` and few other commands in the second script, but no luck. Please help me with this.

Comment: So, you ask some questions, keep the users' answers in variable and print them out.Why do you need a second script for then ?

Comment: @Andre Gelinas, This is my requirement. consider i cannot modify the ScriptA.sh because of some sort of compliance restriction. So i want to build something that can call this script and whenever the script(ScriptA.sh)  asks for some user input, i can pass those values from my script. It's bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not specifying any shell in your tag, this is a possible, albeit crude, solution in ksh. It's using the coprocess capability of that shell (pretty sure it's not supported in bash although please don't quote me on that one)

```
#!/bin/ksh

./ScriptA.sh |&

while read -p Dummy; do
        print $Dummy
        case $Dummy in
                "Enter the CR Number")print -p "CR123456"
                                        ;;
                "3.MAR")print -p "3"
                                ;;
                "Will run the script"*)print -p "y"
                                ;;
        esac
done
```

The output gives :

```
Enter the CR Number
CR Number is CR123456
Loading the config set. Choose Option From Below set
1.JAN
2.FEB
3.MAR
Option Choosen is : 3
Will run the script/load configuration is this Ok ?[y/N]
Proceed further, User has pressed ->y<--Key
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help here. i was not aware of this utility. Now i can look into my project requirement based on this ksh feature. However, are you aware of anything similar in bash ?

Comment: No sorry, don't know bash enough.

Answer (score 0):

Will input remain same everytime? If so you can create wrapper of this script to provide required input.

```
cat wrapper
./ScriptA.sh <<!
123
2
y
!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the requirement is to pass different values for different cases.